# Unable to send JSONObject using Retrofit POST?

Tags: android

So I have a JSONObject's object and I need to send the object to backend using Retrofit. It is a POST api and the body is of jsonObject. The following code I have written send JSONObject.

This is interface

```
    public interface ApiSet {
         @POST(Api.DELETE_EWAYBILL)
            Call<JsonElement> deleteEwaybill(@Body JSONObject jsonObject);
        }
```

This code I written in adapter

```
    Call<JsonElement> call = ApiController.getInstance()
            .getApi()
            .deleteEwaybill(deleteEwayObj);
    Log.e("vin1", deleteEwayObj.toString());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, retrofit2.Response<JsonElement> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                JsonElement jsonElement = response.body();
                if(jsonElement.isJsonObject()){
                    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                    PostResponse postResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, PostResponse.class);
                    if(postResponse.isSuccess()){
                        ((Activity) context).recreate();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(context,postResponse.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("vin1", "delete invoice error = "+postResponse.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
            customProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("vin1", "retrofit failure = " + t.getMessage());
            customProgressDialog.dismiss();
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you share error message?

Comment: Something went wrong is the only response i got.